# A poset which has no upper bound for some chain and no maximal element

Tags: set-theory

Zorn's lemma states that if every chain of a partially ordered set $A$ has an upper bound in $A$, then $A$ contains at least one maximal element.

The question is: does there exist a partially ordered set $B$ such that

1)Some number of chains of $B$ have no upper bound in $B$ (while some chains of $B$ do)

2)$B$ contains no maximal elements?

Answer (score 3):

The set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ ordered by the usual $<$ has this property: infinite chains have no upper bound, finite chains do, and there's clearly no maximal element.